# autosys - run list of jobs one after another (order in jil must reflect dependency)

Tags: autosys

I have a list of jobs to be done SEQUENTIALLY (one after another). If I list all my jobs in

```
---- myjobsBox.jil---
# cleanup-db Jobsinsert_job: **CleanupDB_Box**
job_type: b 
date_conditions: yes 
days_of_week: all 
start_times: "02:00, 17:00"


#########   dbpurge1

insert_job: dbpurge1
job_type: c
box_name: CleanupDB_Box
command: cmd1
machine: mymachine.com
permission: mx,
std_out_file: /var/tmp/cleanupdb.log
std_err_file: /var/tmp/cleanupdb.err
alarm_if_fail: 1


#########   dbpurge2
insert_job: dbpurge2
job_type: c
box_name: CleanupDB_Box
command: cmd1
machine: mymachine.com
permission: mx,
std_out_file: /var/tmp/cleanupdb.log
std_err_file: /var/tmp/cleanupdb.err
alarm_if_fail: 1
condition: done(dbpurge1) # Can I avoid this? Is there a way to tell-the-box to execute the jobs in the order in which it is mentioned in jil file?
#########   dbpurge3
insert_job: dbpurge3
job_type: c
box_name: CleanupDB_Box
command: cmd1
machine: mymachine.com
permission: mx,
std_out_file: /var/tmp/cleanupdb.log
std_err_file: /var/tmp/cleanupdb.err
alarm_if_fail: 1
condition: done(dbpurge2) # Can I avoid this?
```

condition: done(dbpurge1) # Can I avoid this?

Is there a way to tell-the-box to execute the jobs in the order in which it is present in jil file? ONE-AFTER-OTHER.. SEQUENTIAL .. NOT-PARALLEL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't a way to do that, you must use the condition parameter.
Is there any particular reason why you want to avoid the use of the condition parameter?